# How to change RecyclerView number of rows at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I have a recycler view full of images and I wanted to know how I can changed the number of rows, not columns at runtime in Java using android studio.

So if I was creating a recycler view with a Grid Layout as such:

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

This means I am setting the RecyclerView to have 4 columns.

If this was the contents of the each Recycler item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NewImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How would I change it so I could for example have 1 row on a page, or two rows or three.

I attempted to do it this way

```
        public FlagDataVHolder(LayoutInflater li, ViewGroup parent, int inNumRows)
        {
            super(li.inflate(R.layout.flag, parent, false));

            newImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newImageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            //Adjust the size of the ViewHolder based on the number of rows
            //Get the screen size
            int screenWidth = parent.getMeasuredWidth();
            int screenHeight = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
            if (inNumRows == 1)
            {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = screenHeight;
            }
            else if (inNumRows == 2)
            {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = screenHeight/2;
            }
            else
            {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = screenHeight/3;
            }
        }
```

So depending on the number of rows, which can be 1,2,3 the program would divide the item view size to fractions of the screen size.

But this didn't work so I wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: please add some more data to answer.

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari I added lots more detail